# Please advise on VPS config choice (with SQL Server Express)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, hyper-v, vps

I might be interested in getting a VPS hosting plan for some small personal sites and .NET projects. Was thinking of Softsys Bronze Plan, as my current shared host plan is with them too. The stuff I want to host has grown beyond the capabilities of a Shared hosting plan, and I also want more control over the IIS/ASP.NET configuration, that's why I'm considering VPS.

The main config details would be:

- Hyper-V
- 30 GB of diskspace
- 1 GB of RAM

More info here: http://www.softsyshosting.com/Windows-VPS-HyperV.aspx

Does anyone have experience with this plan (or something similar from another host), and maybe could answer these couple of questions:

- Bronze has a total diskspace of 30GB. Is the OS part of this quota or not ? If so, how much does a base configuration with Windows 2008 take up in diskspace ?
- Would you advise Windows 2008 R2 or Normal. Or would you advise to use Windows 2003 with this config.
- I'm planning on running a SQL Server Express install too. Would 1 GB of RAM be enough for both the Windows 2008 (R2) and SQL Express. The database load will not be that very high (a couple of 1000 records returned each day). The DB will most likely be far away from the 4GB limit, that's why I'd go for a SQL Express instead of paying extra licensing costs for a SQL Web install. But I'm more concerned about performance.
- Would you recommend Softsys as a VPS host ? I've been with them for one year for my Shared hosting plan, and have no complaints so far.

Also, as I have no VPS experience, what are the pitfalls I need to be aware of, in terms of performance mainly, but maybe in other areas too ?

Mathieu

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm planning on running a SQL Server
>   Express install too. Would 1 GB of RAM
>   be enough for both the Windows 2008
>   (R2) and SQL Express. The database
>   load will not be that very high (a
>   couple of 1000 records returned each
>   day). The DB will most likely be far
>   away from the 4GB limit, that's why
>   I'd go for a SQL Express instead of
>   paying extra licensing costs for a SQL
>   Web install. But I'm more concerned
>   about performance."

1GB is workable (but not good) for IIS and SQL Express.  My bigger concern would be remote desktopping into there and starting SSMS, services, Windows Explorer, etc.  As long as you never remote desktop in, it'll work, but nobody's jaws are going to drop with the blazing speed.  Just be good about query optimization.

Comment: Yeah, on 2003 I made it by with 1GB and it wasn't awful but I had to hard set the limit on SQL server to allow space for other services to run. On 2GB these days and it's much better.

Answer (score 1):

> Bronze has a total diskspace of 30GB. Is the OS part of this quota or not ? If so, how much does a base configuration with Windows 2008 take up in diskspace ?

I doubt that is seperate from windows. MS recommended 20GB minimum, I'd look at more disk.

> Also, as I have no VPS experience, what are the pitfalls I need to be aware of, in terms of performance mainly, but maybe in other areas too ?

Disk IO will most likely be the biggest issue, it really depends on your provider. I guess you have to test it to see.

> the Windows 2008 (R2) and SQL Express. The database load will not be that very high (a couple of 1000 records returned each day). The DB will most likely be far away from the 4GB limit, that's why I'd go for a SQL Express instead of paying extra licensing costs for a SQL Web install. But I'm more concerned about performance.

It is doable but I'd really suggest getting more ram.

Answer (score 1):

I personally never recommend running a VPS as both a WWW and DB server.  The I/O bottleneck threshold starts to creep on up too quickly.  It's best to always run the DB server on dedicated hardware.  I'd say your best bet is to see if they also have a shared dedicated DB server that you could add databases to as needed.  You could use the VPS as a dedicated IIS server and see far better performance in the long run.

I'd also go with the Silver package.  Dual core FTW

Comment: +1 on that. Especially as you dont know the IO threshhold. I run both on VPS but now my disc count just hits 14 ;) And I still lag on the discs.